# pytorch make customized gradient update with label

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I want to make customized gradient update like below, modifying backprop value of midlayer (dL/dx_midlayer = dL/dx_midlayer + some_custom_value_using_'label')

```py
for epoch in range(epochs):
    x, y = some_inputs
    output = model(x)
    loss = criterion(output, label)

    backprop_grad_until_last_conv = loss.backward_until_last_conv...()
    x_hat = last_conv_input_features
    backprop_grad_until_last_conv += customfunc(x_hat, label, epoch)

    loss.backward_after_last_conv...()
    optimizer.step()
```

I made a layer for custom backward function, but cannot get label and epoch argument because torch.nn.Module 's backward argument is (self, grad_output), so I just make a backward function that can use 'label' and 'epoch'

are there any way that can do that..?